# zosftplib submit_wait_job() function parameters

Tags: python-3.x, ftplib, zos

While I'm trying to submit a job using function submit_wait_job() from my python script which is as below

```
import zosftplib as Zoe
FTP= Zoe.Zftp("server","username", "PWD")

FTP.submit_wait_job(jcl="DO0.TEST.JCL(TESTJOB)", jobname="TESTJOB")
```

I'm getting following error

```
zosftplib.ZftpError: 'submit_wait_job error : Invalid jobcard : \ 'D00.TEST.JCL(TESTJOB)\' in JCL file
```

I have searched over web how to configure this function but no luck. What are correct values to be passed to the parameters of this function ?

Comment: The error message says the jobcard in D00.TEST.JCL(TESTJOB) is invalid.  What happens if you just submit the job via ISPF?  Are there any more helpful error messages in SDSF (presuming you're running SDSF)?

Comment: @cschneid when I submit from ispf it's running fine. With maxcc = 0 as RC

Comment: Are there any errors in the SYSLOG you can see that seem associated with the attempts to submit via the Python library?  They may be on a different LPAR than the one you normally log on to.

Comment: to me the error message is quite clear: the `jcl`-parameter should contain a JCL-string, not a datasetname that contains the JCL. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any exact documentation of those functions and their parameters.

Comment: @piet.t using retrlines function I was able to pass the whole jcl as string to this function. And now it's working fine. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try use like `DO0.TEST.JCL(TESTJOB)`